# $C^3$ boundary, locally the Levi form satisfies $L(r,t)\geq -C|r(z)||t|^2$ for tangent vectors $t$ and defining function $r$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I've been reading Range's *Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables* and I am currently stuck on some techincal details in the proof of Lemma 2.19:

> A bounded Levi pseudoconvex domain $D$ with $C^3$ boundary is pseudoconvex (i.e. has a strictly plurisubharmonic exhaustion function).

But my issues boil down to the following: Suppose we have a $C^3$ defining function $r$ defined on some open set $U$ containing a point $P\in bD$. Define the Levi form as (with $t\in\mathbb{C}^n$)
$$
L_z(r,t)=\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial z_j\partial \bar{z}_k}(z)t_j\bar{t}_k.
$$
Fix $w\in\mathbb{C}^n$. At each $z\in bD$, we may orthogonally decompose $w$ as $w=w'_z+w''_z$, where $w_z'\in T^{\mathbb{C}}_z(bD)$ and $w_z''\in T_z^{\mathbb{C}}(bD)^{\perp}$, and furthermore $w'_z$ and $w''_z$ both depend differentiably on $z$. I want to show that, by shrinking $U$ if necessary,
$$
L_z(r,w_z')\geq -C|r(z)||w_z'|^2.
$$
for some positive constant $C>0$. Supposedly this is possible since $z\mapsto L_z(r,w_z')$ belongs to $C^1$. I've thought about this for an embarrassingly long time. Here are my ideas so far.

**Ideas**

Consider the function $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(z)=L_z(r,w_z')
$$
Fix $\zeta\in bD$. By Taylor's theorem, we have
$$
f(z)=f(\zeta)+O(|z-\zeta|)\geq O(|z-\zeta|),
$$
where the inequality follows from pseudoconvexity. This implies there exists a $C>0$ such that
$$
f(z)=L_z(r,w'_z)=\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial z_j\partial\bar{z}_k}(w'_z)_j\overline{(w'_z)_k}\geq -C|z-\zeta|.
$$
Now from here I'm tempted to use the fact that $|z-\zeta|\geq\text{dist}(z,bD)=-h(z)|r(z)|$ for some positive function $h$, but with the negative sign in front of the $C$ this inequality is useless.

I'm sure I'm overthinking things and there's probably an easier way. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: archive.org book link: https://archive.org/stream/springer_10.1007-978-1-4757-1918-5/10.1007-978-1-4757-1918-5#page/n79/mode/2up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$w'_z$ is the projection of $w$ onto the tangent space of $r$ at $z.$ Since we're just talking about a bilinear form, it suffices to show $L_z(r,w'_z)\geq -C|r(z)|$ for $|w'_z|\approx 1$ (e.g. $\tfrac12\leq|w'_z|\leq 2$). Shrink $U$ to a bounded set. So we can consider $r$ and $w'_z$ to be bounded which makes things easier. $L_z(r,w'_z)$ is a $C^1$ function in $z$ on a bounded set, so it's bounded below by some negative constant multiplied by the distance to any point in $bD.$ This means it's at least $-C|r(z)|\max(|\partial r/\partial z|^{-1})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a question:
It seems that the main point is that my last displayed inequality above holds for $z\in D$ and _any_ $\zeta\in bD$, so you can take the infimum over such $\zeta$, yielding the distance to the boundary $\text{d}(z,bD)$. However, the way I see it, the aforementioned inequality only holds for those $\zeta\in bD$ having the property that the neighborhood $U$ about $\zeta$ which the Taylor expansion of $f$ holds also contains $z$? How do you sidestep this issue?
Also, would it not suffice to assume $|w'_z|=1$ and not just $|w'_z|\approx1$?

Comment: Ahh I think I see. I'm so used to working with analytic functions I was thinking that the representation of $f$ (or $r$) arising from Taylor's theorem only holds in a neighborhood of a point. Is this what I am missing?

Comment: @Blake: $|w'_z|=1$ would suffice, but it might be slightly cleaner easier to set $|w|=1$ so $|w'_z|\in(1/2,1]$ say. You can use Taylor's theorem with remainder along a path, though since this is using only a first order derivative I would think of it as a Lipschitz bound.

Comment: @Blake: I've noticed that turning a $r$ bound into a bound on the distance to $bD$ is a bit subtler than I thought - I think the cleanest approach is to use the implicit function theorem to argue that $r$ behaves like a projection onto a co-ordinate axis (though then the $L_z(r,w'_z)$ notation gets confusing...